# How to get list of groups from LinkedIn in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

I am using LinkedIn API to get list of groups:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/group-memberships:(group:(id,name))?count=100&start=0
```

Before this was working fine, but now I am getting this error:

> ***errorCode: 0,***
>
> ***message: Access to group-memberships denied,***
>
> ***requestId: P5RCF85CT4,***
>
> ***status: 403,***

Help me how to retrieve a list of groups.

Comment: Linkedin made changes to their developer program recently. Did you consider this? https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes

Answer (score 0):

**Starting from [May 12, 2015](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes), Linkedin has limited the open APIs. 
Access to `Groups` requires that you apply for and are granted access to this information from LinkedIn.**

**Solution :**

Apply for partner status with LinkedIn ([Apply with Linkedin](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin)), explaining what your application is and how it works. If it meets their criteria, then you will get access to those endpoints, but only for that app.